# detect click on childNode and send trough event handler

Tags: javascript

I have this event handler:

```
//Event Handler
var bindEvt = (function () {
    "use strict";
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        return function (element, event, handler) {
            element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
        };
    }
    return function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
    };
}());
```

And this code which cycles trough menu elements and detects if one is clicked.

```
// Ajax article loading
function test(){var menuitem = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].childNodes;
    for(var i= 0; i < menuitem.length; i++){
        bindEvt(menuitem[i], "click", loadajax);
    }
};

function loadajax () {
    alert('yo')
}
bindEvt(window, "load", test);
```

Now my problem is that I would like `loadajax()` to know what item was clicked but I cannot seem to figure out how to pass an argument from `test()` to `loadajax()`.

How would I do this? I tried a couple of things but it always seems to break the script :(

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is to know which object was clicked, then you can use the value of `this` in your event handler.  You don't have to pass that to loadajax.  The event system will set `this` to the object that caused the event.  You can also reference `event.target`.

```
function loadajax (event) {
    event = event || window.event;   // deal with old IE

    // `this` points to the object that caused the event

    alert('yo');
}
```

Comment: Just tried that before your edit and indeed, I didn't get the value of [i]... Might you know of a solution to this?

Comment: DUDE that did it :D, a simple "this"... It is pretty obvious now. Thanks :). Perfect answer

Comment: hm cleaner answer indeed :). I didn't know "this" got set system wide and not only inside a specific function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadajax (X) {
console.log(X);
alert('yo')
}
```

X should be of type Event and have lotsa good detail:

```
interface Event {

  // PhaseType
  const unsigned short      CAPTURING_PHASE                = 1;
  const unsigned short      AT_TARGET                      = 2;
  const unsigned short      BUBBLING_PHASE                 = 3;

  readonly attribute DOMString        type;
  readonly attribute EventTarget      target;
  readonly attribute EventTarget      currentTarget;
  readonly attribute unsigned short   eventPhase;
  readonly attribute boolean          bubbles;
  readonly attribute boolean          cancelable;
  readonly attribute DOMTimeStamp     timeStamp;
  void               stopPropagation();
  void               preventDefault();
  void               initEvent(in DOMString eventTypeArg, 
                               in boolean canBubbleArg, 
                               in boolean cancelableArg);
};
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event